# How to get the row count in item processor?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there any way to get the current row number of the file that is being processed inside item processor without implementing listeners?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your item implements the [ItemCountAware Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemCountAware.html), spring batch will fill the current row number for you

ps: i am almost 100% sure that a similar question and answer already exists here at stackoverflow, but i did not found it